# How to make fantasize compatible with buttons

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

When I increase or decrease the fontSize in the phone the buttons becomes bigger or smaller but I want to make my buttons look same in the all fontSizes. How can I force my app to use just default font size or make compatible with fontSize

[my xml code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UQ-lxdkFBNPYz2FpN_xGz5kmI0RZwuB6vx3O6980uxE/edit?usp=sharing)

Normal fontSize:

[image: 1Normal fontSize]

Larger fontSize:

[image: 2Larger fontSize]

Smaller fontSize:

[image: 3Smaller fontSize]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should fix the size of button instead of wrap/match size,if you have not given fix size then use this tag in LinearLayout

```
android:layout_weight="int"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Device Settings font size affects only sizes in sp. So all You need to do - define textSize in dp instead of sp, then settings won't change text size in Your app. Click [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

```
android:textSize="xxdp"
```

Alought this will include unwanted behavior in your app from user point of view.

**Option2**

Fix Button's `android:layout_width="xxdp"` and `android:layout_height="xxdp"`

Again this can also bring unwanted layout view.

if you want to make sure you actually fix the button size exactly how you want then use both options. i.e. use `dp` and user fix `width` and `height` on button.

Happy Coding !